# TexStudio, using list of 'bad words'

Tags: texstudio

I would like to use the option of TexStudio of having a 'bad words' list. I know where to find the wordlist directory. In here there is the bad word list for the German language (that works well when I switch to German). However I can't create my own list of bad words for the English language. How to create such a list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to create a `en_US.badWords` (or `en_GB.badWords`, regarding the language you chose) file and save it in the same folder than `de_DE.badWords` (keeping the same structure, i.e. one word per line)?